# How to design a website (from mobile design) that is not looking great on desktops

Tags: javascript, css, web, responsive

We have a website designed for mobile, and its appearance and operation are awful on desktop. I want to make a change to the CSS or javascript/jquery of the website so that it will be rendered good on the desktop. for example by something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    width: 500px;
    background-image: * ;
  }
}
```

One of the problems to be solved is that the vw's used to make the display responsive for different mobile sizes would be so big on the desktop that would mess everything.
please help thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Vw or viewport width is a percentage of the screen size. (So 10vw is 10% of the screen's width) Which means that vw always keeps the same size ratio regardless of what screen it is on. If you want to change a certain css element's size when screen width exceeds a certain size in px than add a new media query with a minimum width of a desktop screen. For example 1920px.

Answer (score 1):

You can try search for ideas in bootstrap's classes and methodologies, like using different class modifiers for different screen sizes (col, col-md, col-xl, etc)

As Jalen said, you might want to look into inserting media query and breakpoints at sizes that you find less usable, and optimize those.

From experience, making an existing app reactive (meaning that it can run in both enviroments with a single codebase) can be daunting, but with few changes in css and templates you might be able to achieve it